# Type extends Record but not and interface?

Tags: typescript

I'd like help trying to explain the following

```
interface IProps {
  userId: string
  hedgerId: string
}

type a = IProps extends Record<string, string> ? true : false
// a is false
```

But here:

```
type a = {
  userId: string
  hedgerId: string
} extends Record<string, string> ? true : false
// a is true
```

Why the difference?

Comment: See [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) and the answer to the linked question